# Сумма списка в зависимости от пользовательского ввода

Tags: python, list

Как вывести сумму списка в Python, если количество чисел списка равно числу n из пользовательского ввода? Я написала код но выдает ошибку. Подскажите, как решить задачу если ввод должен быть:

```
5
4 1 8 1 1
```

А вывод:

```
15
```

Вот мой код, который выдает ошибку:

```
 n=int(input())
 m=[]
 for i in range(n):
    m.append(int(input()))
 s=0
 for i in range(n):
     s=s+m[i]
 print(s)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/source.py", line 4, in <module>
    m.append(int(input()))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 1 8 1 1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы избежать этой проблемы, можно пробовать использовать `input().split()` для разделения введенных значений, а затем преобразовывать их в `int` с помощью `map`.

```
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())
s = sum(arr)
print(s)
```

- input().split() сначала считывает строку введенную с клавиатуры, затем разбивает ее на подстроки с помощью пробела (по умолчанию).
- map - это встроенная функция в Python, которая применяет указанную функцию к каждому элементу итерируемого объекта
- sum - это встроенная функция Python, которая принимает итерируемый объект (например, список) в качестве аргумента и возвращает сумму всех элементов

Comment: Большое спасибо, програма приняла решение:)

Comment: @LADOK тогда нажмите на галку возле ответа

Comment: @Vladyslav я бы на вашем месте сделал бы более подробное объяснение, всё-таки ТС – новичок, и это стоит учитывать.

Comment: @NNL993 добавил описание

Comment: @Vladyslav да, теперь намного лучше! С меня плюсик.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнительные разъяснения)